# Issues with Custom Tab Bar when using UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl

Tags: ios, uitabbar, tabbar, uimodaltransitionstyle

I've added a custom tab bar which works well however when i present another view modally using  `UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl` the image for the tab bar continues on. Image below:

[image: Screenshot]

I've added the tabBar image like this:

```
if([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 5.0)
{        
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navigationBarBackground.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
}
```

And then I just present the view modally on a button hit, i've tried a couple different things and can't get it to change. Do you have any idea?